# Infinite automorphism group implies that Riemann surface is a disk or an annulus?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose I have a bounded, connected Riemann surface whose automorphism group is infinite. Does it follow (and if yes why) that the Riemann surface is homeomorphic to a disk or an annulus?

Trying to find something about this question, I have found Hurwitz's Automorphism Theorem, from which it seems to follow that every compact Riemann surface with more than one hole must have finite automorphism group.
Unfortunately I am no expert in geometry, so I am not sure if I can apply this theorem here. In particular, my Riemann surface is not compact but open, so this might be a problem.
Or anyway, is there an easier way to prove the claim?

Comment: What about torus, sphere, sphere- 4 points etc?

Comment: @Anubhav would the answer change, if I restrict myself to non-compact Riemann surfaces?

Comment: Automorphism group of closed Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$ are finite.